# TaylorSeries of complete elliptic integral of the first kind

Tags: integration, functions, taylor-expansion, elliptic-integrals

I want compute $K(k)$ as a Taylor Series; $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\vert k \vert < 1$.
Can someone help me?
$$
K(k):= \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2t}}
$$
Results so far:
$$
K(k):= \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2t}} = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 (1-k^2 \sin^2t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dt
$$
With using binomial Series we get
$$
\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \sum^\infty_{\Phi=0} {-\frac{1}{2} \choose \Phi}(-k^{2\Phi}){\sin^{2\Phi}{t}} \ dt = \sum^\infty_{\Phi=0} {-\frac{1}{2} \choose \Phi}(-k^{2\Phi})\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\sin^{2\Phi}t \ dt
$$
For $\Phi$ even:
$$
\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\sin^{2\Phi}t \ dt = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{5}{6}...\frac{n-1}{n} = S
$$
thus we get:
$$
 1. \sum^\infty_{\Phi=0} {-\frac{1}{2} \choose \Phi}(-k^{2\Phi})\cdot S
$$
now i need some help to compute 1. as taylor series, can someone help?

Thanks! Landau.

Comment: Note: the standard notation for the complete elliptic integral of the first kind is $K(k)$. $E(k)$ usually refers to the complete elliptic integral of the *second* kind.

Comment: Oh i didn't know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generating function for central binomial coefficient is given by [mathworld site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html).

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4 \left( \frac {k^2} 4 \sin^2 (t) \right )}} dt &= \int_0^{\frac \pi 2 } \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \left(\frac {k^2} 4 \sin^2 (t) \right )^n dt \\ 
 &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n}  \frac{k^{2n}}{4^n} \cdot \frac 1 2  \cdot \beta (n+1/2, 1/2) \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2 2^{2n}  }\cdot \frac 1 2  \left( \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} \right ) k^{2n}\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2 2^{2n}  }\cdot \frac 1 2 \left( \frac{(2n)! \sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{\pi}}{(n!)^2} \right ) k^{2n} \\ 
&= \frac{ \pi }{2 } \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left( \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^{2} 2^{2n}}  \right )^2 k^{2n}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_{2n}(0)k^{2n}
\end{align*}

Where $P_{n}(0)$ is Legendre polynomial. Seems that [wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B2%20n,%20n%5D%20k%5E%282%20n%29/%282%204%5En%29%20Beta%5Bn%20%2b%201/2,%201/2%5D,%20%7Bn,%200,%20%20%20%20Infinity%7D%5D) gives the sum of the right side as `EllipticK[k^2]`. Also it is given here on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: Mathematica writes `EllipticK[m]`, where the parameter $m$ is the square of the modulus $k$ used by Maple when it writes `EllipticK(k)`.

Comment: Maxima uses also $k^2$. It's a well-known trap, that one must be very careful with the argument, when using a software package for elliptic integrals...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I noticed thanks, as mentioned on wikipedia, it uses $k$ while Mathematica seemed to use $k^2$ :/